# Prove inequality $\|Z\|_2\le \|Z\|_1^{1/4} \|Z\|_3^{3/4}$

Tags: probability

Prove $\|Z\|_2\le \|Z\|_1^{1/4} \|Z\|_3^{3/4}$ for random variable $Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder's inequality,

$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=\mathbb{E}[Z^{1/2}Z^{3/2}]\le (\mathbb{E}|Z|)^{1/2}(\mathbb{E}|Z|^3)^{1/2}$$

Rearrange and then it is proved.